# Get match with excluded characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text `3571157, 357-11-57, 357 11 57`

I can catch these numbers with regex `\d{3}[-\s]?\d{2}[-\s]?\d{2}`

but what I want is my match look like `3571157` in all cases. Is even possible?

P.S. I mean on regex level, without additional code after, to make more clear in code `/[a-z-]+/.exec('ha-ha')[0]` I wanna ouput `haha` (match with excluded `-` character)

Comment: What language are you working in? Likely, you'll want some kind of string join or replacement function.

Comment: Are the numbers comma delimited in the text your processing?

Comment: Use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): `(\d{3})[-\s]?(\d{2})[-\s]?(\d{2})` and subtitute with `\1\2\3`. See a demo here: https://regex101.com/r/ee5WAE/1. Of course, the way to do so depends on what programming language (or tool) you're using as @ggorlen has indicated.

Comment: `["3571157", "357-11-57", "357 11 57"].map(x => x.split(/\D+/).join(""))` - If JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is viable. You might do so with a string replace on <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>, such as:

```
$input = '3571157, 357-11-57,  81749 91741 9080,  81749 91741 9080,  81749 91741 9080  ,357 11 57, 81749 91741 9080';
$split_inputs = preg_split('/,/s', $input);
$output = '';
foreach ($split_inputs as $key => $value) {
    $match = preg_match('/^[0-9 \-]{7,9}$/s', trim($value));
    if (!$match) {continue;}
    $output .= preg_replace('/-|\s/s', '', $value);
    if (sizeof($split_inputs) - 1 - $match != (int) $key) {
        $output .= ", ";
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

#### Output

```
 string(25) "3571157, 3571157, 3571157"
```

You may use [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/r9mgIT/1) and match your input first.

```
^[0-9\s\-]{7,9}$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no programming language tagged, but if you get the matches from the string you can replace all non digits using `\D+` with an empty string leaving only the digits.

An example using Javascript:

```js
let str = "3571157, 357-11-57, 357 11 57";
let pattern = /\d{3}[-\s]?\d{2}[-\s]?\d{2}/g;
console.log(str.match(pattern).map(s => s.replace(/\D+/g, '')));
```